# template and what is created during compilation

Tags: c++, templates

if i have a template function:

```
template<class T, class S>
void foo(T t, S s){..//do something//}
```

and then, inside the main i do this:

```
string str = "something";
char* ch = "somthingelse";
double num = 1.5;
foo(ch, num);
foo(num, ch);
foo(str, num);
..
```

my question is in the compilation what code will be written at the executable?
is it will be:

```
foo<char*, double>(..);
foo<double, char*>(..);
foo<string, double>(..);
```

or the compile will know at the second call to foo to change the place of the classes.
or in the 3rd one, in implicit way to use char* to create a string class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following quote from the Standard clarifies this:

> $14.9.1/6- "Implicit conversions
>   (Clause 4) will be performed on a
>   function argument to convert it to the
>   type of the corresponding function
>   parameter if the parameter type
>   contains no template-parameters that
>   participate in template argument
>   deduction. [ Note: template parameters
>   do not participate in template
>   argument deduction if they are
>   explicitly specified."

Since in this case the parameter types of the function template participate in function template argument deduction, no implicit conversion e.g. of string to char * take place.

Comment: can i ask you where did you find this?

Comment: N3126 is not[yet] a Standard. I would recommend you to quote from the C++03 Standard(C++0x is not yet a Standard mind you) instead of quoting from N3126 etc etc...

Answer (score 3):

Usually it will instantiate all three. They will not seek default-cast-workarounds to save binary image space.

Answer (score 2):

il will not implicitly use

```
foo<string, double>(...)
```

for

```
foo(str, num)
```

but you can explicitly ask to use it, i.e. by calling

```
foo(string(str), num)
```